# Send XML over Arduino Ethernet socket

Tags: xml, sockets, arduino

I have done a simple software to measure temperature. What I wan't is to send XML to external browser or some other software. When I connect with browser to the Arduino I get this picture (below). What I'am doing wrong?:

[image]

the code which send xml is:

```
EthernetClient client = server.available();
if (client) {
Serial.println("new client");
// an http request ends with a blank line
boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
while (client.connected()) {
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.write(c);

     if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
      client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
      client.println("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
      client.println("Connection: close");  // the connection will be closed after completion of the response
      client.println();
      client.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
      client.println("<TEMP>");

      client.print(calcTemp(cnt1), 3);
      client.println("<TEMP/>");


      break;
    }
    if (c == '\n') {
      // you're starting a new line
      currentLineIsBlank = true;
    } else if (c != '\r') {
      // you've gotten a character on the current line
      currentLineIsBlank = false;
    }
  }
}
// give the web browser time to receive the data
delay(1);
client.stop();
```

Answer (score 1):

The line 4 where the error has been detected is the following:

```
client.println("<TEMP/>");
```

The correct syntax to close a Xml tag is:

```
client.println("</TEMP>");
```

> Note: the syntax `<TEMP/>` is used to declare an empty attribute. It is equivalent to `<TEMP></TEMP>`.